# Divisibility proof - alternative?

Tags: induction, alternative-proof

I want to prove that $5^{2n}-2^{3n}$ is divisible by 17 for all positive integers $n$. I know this can be done by induction (sketch proof shown below) but want to know if:

1. Are there any alternative proof methods that do not use induction?
2. How many different induction proof approaches are possible for a question such as this? (By different I mean different groupings of terms or perhaps adding and subtracting a new term).

$P(1): 5^{2}-2^{3}=17$ which is divisible by 17, so $P(1)$ is true.

Now, we need to show that the truth of $P(k)$ implies the truth of $P(k+1)$ which means showing that if $5^{2k}-2^{3l}$ is divisible by 17 for some positive integer $k$ then $5^{2(k+1)}-2^{3(k+1)}$ is also divisible by 17.

$5^{2(k+1)}-2^{3(k+1)}=25\times 5^{2k}-8\times 2^{3k}$

$=17\times 5^{2k}+8\times 5^{2k}-8\times 2^{3k}$

$=17\times 5^{2k}+8(5^{2k}-2^{3k})$

Then by $P(1)$, $5^{2k}-2^{3k}$ is divisible by 17 so we can write $5^{2k}-2^{3k}=17s$

$P(k+1)$ then becomes $17\times 5^{2k}+8\times 17s$ from which the result follows.

What other approaches (if any) are possible and how are they different?

Comment: Your question(s!) need more focus. Especially the second one and the final one are far too vague. I think you'd better restrict to the first one.

Comment: $5^{2n}-2^{3n}=25^n-8^n=(25-8)q$ where $q$ is etc., etc.

Comment: You can approch it using modular arithmetics

Comment: Using modular arithmetics , the proof is a "one-liner" : $$5^{2n}=25^n\equiv 8^n=2^{3n}\mod 17$$ We just used $25\equiv 8\mod 17$.